Android Studio: how to display the contents of another activity onto a CardView?
so i'm working on a moodboard app, and my task right now is to create a menu. You can create and select the boards with the menu, and selecting them will direct you to a blank moodboard, where you can then add images. (example images given) I need to have the cards on the menu display whatever images the user has added onto the moodboard.
i'm using the homeboard light app as a reference... i'm not sure how to do it myself. I've done the CardViews and the moondboard screens themselves. now, all i need is to figure out how to display the moodboards...
examples pics!!
the menu/cards that display the contents of a separate activity
the activity with contents!
on the activity where you add the images, i used an ImageView
and the menu, i used CardViews.
I thought using drawables can work and use that as a background but I could not figure out how to do it (sorry i'm a student and O unfortunately have not been taught much about this yet ).

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Make a static member which stores the image bytes typically in a bytearray which you can access from your other activity then and set the image like imageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(IMAGEBYTES, 0, IMAGEBYTES.length));. Make sure to set the static member to null once you dont need it anymore.
